# Multi DC replication between different Cassandra versions

Tags: cassandra, replication

We have an existing Cassandra cluster (3.0.9) running on production.

Now ,we want to create data pipelines to ingest data from Cassandra and persist in hadoop. We are thinking of using CDC feature (available from Cassandra 3.8) along with Kafka Connect.

[image]

We are thinking of creating a new read-only DC which will replicate data from the Production DC.This new DC will be running the latest Cassandra version (3.8+) with CDC enabled.

My questions:

1. For replication to work, do we need both dc's running same version of Cassandra? Can't we achieve this without upgrading the DC used by the service?
2. Is it possible to enable CDC feature only in the new read-only DC?

**UPDATE :**
More information from C* mailing list https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r9e705895c480f264998c29cf69c0eb2296382049467e31c447f676c7%40%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E

Comment: As was already stated in the Cassandra mailing list, don't mix versions in a cluster.  Also, upgrading the existing nodes to the latest patch of 3.11 is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it should be the same version as existing DC for replication of the data by adding a DC. you may refer below recommended document below for adding new datacenter in existing cluster.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html

1. You should upgrade the existing DC from lower to upper version of Cassandra to get expected feature.
2. You can make your DC as read only without sending any direct traffic in the new DC. all connection should be on older DC.